Setting 3D-plot scale to logarithmic in Matplotlib giving an almost empty 2D plot
I'm trying to set the scale of a plot to logarithmic, using the code below. When plotting without the log scale, it gives me a correct plot.
for it, folder in enumerate(norm_folder_list):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(folder_data_real[it][0], folder_data_real[it][1], folder_data_real[it][2])

    
    ax.set_xlabel('Frequency')
    ax.set_ylabel('Time')
    ax.set_zlabel('Permittivity')


    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.set_zscale('log')

However, the plot I am obtaining when using the log scale is as follows:

I have never come across this, and can't seem to find anything about it online.
I tried plotting using different libraries, and the different libraries worked. However, for specific reasons, I need to use matplotlib3D for this.

what at the ranges of the data for each of the 3 axes? Can you turn your example into a [MCVE] which still demonstrates the issue? I wonder if one axis has an invalid range (e.g. negative values) which cause the log scale to give strange results.

@tmdavison I believe that that was the issue. It seems that matplotlib is unable to handle such issues internally.

This is a longstanding limitation of matplotlib, follow along with the feature request here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/209

Some values in some of the axes had invalid values for the logarithmic scale. Matplotlib does not account for these and, thus these values need to be removed before attempting to plot.
As an alternative, libraries such as plotly are able to account for these kind of values.
